# How do you store "int" values in an NSMutableArray* or NSMutableDictionary*? Chronic problems with JSON data that come in as integers.

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary, nsnumber

How do you store `"int"` values in an `NSMutableArray` or `NSMutableDictionary`?  Chronic problems with JSON data that come in as integers.

Should I try to store these integers as `NSNumber` objects or just as strings that contain the integer?

How dangerous is it to do a "raw" (int) conversion on the pointers if I know the values will always be Natural Numbers (numbers>=0 including zero for null.)

The integers I'm always working with are Foreign Key Id's from a database.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use NSNumber like this:

```
int yourInt = 5;
[myMutableArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:yourInt]];
```

Or using modern Objective C syntax, you can use the following for expressions:

```
[myMutableArray addObject:@(2 + 3)];
```

Or for lone numbers:

```
[myMutableArray addObject:@5];
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `NSNumber` objects (e.g. using `[NSNumber numberWithInt:value]`)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `NSNumber`, as others have said, or use an `NSString` with the string representaton of the number. It really doesn't matter which, but the `NSNumber` will be more efficient.

You **can't** just throw in an `int`, let it be interpreted as a pointer, and then cast it back on the way out. The reason is that the object (that the `int` will be interpreted as a pointer to) will be sent the `retain` message when it is added to the array, and this will definately cause a crash since it will be an invalid pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

```
[myDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:anInteger] forKey:@"MyInteger"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add value like this

NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[values addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:23]];