# How do you store “bool” values in an NSMutableArray* or NSMutableDictionary*? Chronic problems with JSON data that come in as bool's

Tags: objective-c, json, ios

This question is similar to: [How do you store "int" values in an NSMutableArray* or NSMutableDictionary*? Chronic problems with JSON data that come in as integers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764391/how-do-you-store-int-values-in-an-nsmutablearray-or-nsmutabledictionary-chr)

How do you do this with Boolean values?

How do you store "bool" values in an NSMutableArray* or NSMutableDictionary*? Chronic problems with JSON data that come in as Boolean values.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can store it as a number:

```
[mutableArray addObject[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
```

**EDIT**
And with the new syntax:

```
 //BOOL
[mutableArray addObject:@YES];
 //integer
 [mutableArray addObject:@23];
```

Answer (score 5):

You should simply wrap the bool in an NSNumber as follows:

```
NSNumber *wrappedBool = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
```

For future reference, [NSNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has quite a few numberWith... methods for wrapping booleans, ints, floats, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [JSON-Framework](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) which abstracts away all those difficulties.

Comment: I'm using an older version of the JSON framework, and it doesn't tell me how to deal with these values directly.  NSNumber seems like the right route.